# Radio button with return false javascript still invoke onchange with old value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, radio-button

I have a radio button that bind to change event and check it's value.
But when that radio button was also bind with on click for disable, it's still invoke change event with clicked value.

How can i fix this problem so it won't call `change` or call `change` without value of clicked radio button.

[Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/q7fhugks/)

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I changed the selector `input[type=radio][name=test]` to `input[type=radio][name=test]:not(.radreadonly)` so that event handler would not be attached to radio buttons with the `readonly` class.

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bcagwd34/1/)